# Linq Enumerable<T>.ElementAt => IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a method in Linq that does the same as `ElementAt` except it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` with a single element, rather than the actual element? Isn't there some `SelectRange(startIndex, endIndex)` method I could use and just pass the same index twice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use

```
source.Skip(count).Take(1)
```

or more generally

```
source.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex)
```

(assuming an inclusive `startIndex` but exclusive `endIndex`).

Comment: If `source` is a `List`, will `Skip(count)` be `O(1)`?

Comment: @Mark: Unfortunately, I don't believe that Skip is optimized for this, no. Bit of a hole, really :(

Answer (score 3):

Ah.. it's called `GetRange(index, count)`. My bad. Just found it :)

Comment: No, that's part of `List` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`, and it will work rather differently (as it's eager).

Comment: @Mark. Only works on `List<T>`. Jon's answer will work for any `IEnumerable`.

Comment: But +1 For still being a notable option in some cases.

Comment: @Jon: What do you mean by "eager"?

Comment: @Mark: It will immediately copy the items, whereas LINQ sequences are lazy - they only look at the data when you start requesting it.

Comment: @Jon: Ah... didn't know that's what you call the opposite of lazy :)

Comment: +1 for that comment @Jon Skeet. Becomes supremely important when using LINQ-Entities. I can see it now: `var deathByLinq = db.Orders.ToList().GetRange()`, why is my computer smoking??

Comment: @RPM: Wouldn't `ToList()` evaluate it immediately too? What's the harm in doing it twice then?

Comment: @Mark - that was my joke, Guess it wasn't that funny. :)

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet's technique is a great way to do it. I would however suggest a *possible* optimization that is based on an implementation detail in `Enumerable.Skip`: it does not currently appear to take advantage of indexers on `IList` or `IList<T>`. Fortunately, `Enumerable.ElementAt` does.

So an alternate solution would be:

```
var itemAsSequence = new[] { source.ElementAt(index) };
```

Do note that this will execute eagerly. If you want deferred execution semantics similar to Jon's answer, you could do something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ElementAtAsSequence<T>
  (this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
{
   // if you need argument validation, you need another level of indirection

   yield return source.ElementAt(index);
}

...

var itemAsSequence = source.ElementAtAsSequence(index);
```

I should point out that since this relies on an implementation detail, future improvements in LINQ to Objects could make this optimization redundant.

Answer (score 1):

write an extension method

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToMyEnumerable<T>(this T input)
    {
        var enumerbale = new[] { input };
        return enumerbale;
    }

    source.First( p => p.ID == value).ToMyEnumerable<T>()
```

which is O(n)